# What is polymorphism if you can already have methods that are the same defined in different types?

Tags: object-oriented, polymorphism

I often read definitions for Polymorphism such as the following:

> Polymorphism is the ability to have objects of different types
>   understanding the same message

But the above definition also apply if we don't use Polymorphism, for example if we have an object of type `Circle` with a method `draw()`, and another object of type `Rectangle` with a method `draw()`, we can do:

```
circle1.draw();
rectangle1.draw();
```

So `circle1` and `rectangle1` understood the same message `draw()` without using Polymorphism!

Am I missing something?

Comment: _"Am I missing something?"_ What is the _Supertype_ of `Circle` and `Rectangle`?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ don't forget that they can have different supertypes yet both implement the `CanDraw` interface. Or this might be a language that supports duck typing. Polymorphism comes in many forms.

Comment: Read [this paper on the ObjJVLisp model](http://stephane.ducasse.free.fr/Web/ArchivedLectures/Lectures-Reflective-0001/allPapers.pdf) and later [Cardelli's *a theory of objects*](http://lucacardelli.name/TheoryOfObjects.html) book

Comment: . In golang for example your circle and rectangle classes might be implicitly implementing multiple interfaces. If you reference the interface to call Draw() then you are exploiting polymorphism. Just because you don't does not mean your code is not polymorphic. The downvoted answer on modus tollens is basically correct. What you are up against is your own logical fallacy. Everything else you understand about polymorphism, including your quote, still holds.

Comment: Try putting `circle1` and `rectangle1` in the same array and loop through the array calling each in turn: `array[x].draw()`. If you can do this then your code is polymorphic. If you can't do this then your code is not polymorphic

Comment: It should be noted that your example is also a [kind of](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hoc_polymorphism) polymorphism.

Comment: Polymorphism _is_ confusing. It seems like it's one thing, but then it seems like it's something else.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ some kind of elongated [squircle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squircle)?

Comment: Well, if you are using Python or Javascript, you could say so; If you use C++, you will need either C++17 or a base class to be able to do: 

```c++
std::vector<Shapes> shapes_to_draw;
shapes_to_draw.push_back(Circle());
shapes_to_draw.push_back(Rectangle());
for(auto drawable: shapes_to_draw) {
    drawable.draw();
}
```

The C++17 version couuld be using a `std::vector<std::variant<Circle, Rectangle>>`

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Yes, that confusion can take many forms.

Comment: @max630 From that page: "It is also known as function overloading or operator overloading."  I don't see how that applies here.

Comment: I edited your title to be specific to the question (as opposed to _any_ possible confusion about polymorphism), so others can hopefully find it.  Please feel free to tweak it if it can be worded better!

Comment: I think one major thing that could help, at least from the perspective of C#, is that inheritance CAN provide polymorphism, but it isn't guaranteed.  An `interface` does guarantee at least some level of polymorphism.

Comment: Google up "static polymorphism" too.

Answer (score 69):

In your example, you don't really show the same message, you show two different messages that happen to have the same name. Polymorphism requires that the *sender* of a message can send it without knowing the exact recipient. Without seeing evidence that the caller can do something like `shape.draw()` without knowing whether `shape` contains a circle or a rectangle, you may or may not have actual polymorphism. They could be as unrelated as `circle.draw()` and `weapon.draw()`.

They don't necessarily have to both implement the same nominal interface. The language could support structural typing or compile-time templating and it would still be called polymorphism. As long as the caller doesn't care who the callee is.

Comment: In fact, this whole example is exactly how rendering engines work - the most basic of algorithms is literally to "sort objects by distance from camera, then call draw" - obviously some efficiencies have been made along the way...

Comment: @Frank That’s explicitly addressed in the answer (Go does structural subtyping).

Comment: *"Polymorphism requires that the sender of a message can send it without knowing the exact recipient"* What do you mean by *"the sender of a message"*, is the sender the function or the programmer?

Comment: @user8437463 I understand it such that the sender is the code which calls `draw`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph oh is that the name for it.thanks

Comment: @user8437463 The “sender” is the code that is calling a method.

Comment: @user8437463 The sender is the the code that calls a method on an object. The idea is, that, under the hood, it's not calling a function directly; instead, the code is saying "hey, object, whatever you might be, see if you can 'draw' yourself" (it's sending the "draw" message to the object). Then some internal mechanism figures out which concrete function to call, based on what the object actually is (that's the conceptual picture; how it's actually made to work under the hood is a separate question).

Comment: @user8437463 BTW, what I mean by "concrete function" - you can think of it like this: somewhere in the loaded, executing program, the instructions that execute a particular, concrete implementation of function are stored; if you invoke that directly, you can only expect that particular implementation to be executed. The message introduces a level of indirection - it doesn't say which particular implementation to invoke, instead, it's a higher level concept, it represents a conceptual operation, and a couple of different concrete functions implement that operation for different kinds of objects

Comment: @user8437463 So when you write code that says "I want you to do this high level operation - you figure out which concrete function to call", you then don't need to care what the actual type of the object is, as long as it can do the "you figure it out" part. This lets you write the same code for working with both circles and rectangles (and any other type that can draw itself). So that's what's going on, even though, syntactically, it just looks like `shape.draw()`.

Answer (score 33):

> Polymorphism is the ability to have objects of different types understanding the same message

This seems like a rather poor explanation of polymorphism to me.  Technically correct but not very helpful in explaining the usefulness of it.  Basically it's backwards to how polymorphism really gets used.  So we can change your example to be like so:

```
circle1.draw();
rectangle1.render();
```

And it would still work just fine.  This is the crux of your confusion.  It's also demonstrative of why 'objects understanding the same message' is not a really helpful explanation.  If I'm a circle, the fact that a rectangle might have the same method doesn't matter to me.  As a circle, I only care about circle things, not stupid cornery shapes.

To understand the value of polymorphism, you need to think about the code that is calling this.  I'm going to start with Python because I think this concept is a little easier to understand in that context.  Consider the following method:

```py
def paint(*shapes):
  for shape in shapes:
    shape.draw()
```

In this case we can pass any object to this method and as long as it has a `draw()` method that accepts zero parameters, it will send the 'draw' message to each thing.  This is a form of polymorphism called 'duck-typing'.  So your initial example could be aligned with this kind of approach.  If I change the rectangle's method to `render()` then it will fail when a rectangle is passed in.  There would no longer be a common (implicit) interface.

The potential pitfall is that not every type might understand the 'draw' message the same way.  For example, if you pass in a `Gunslinger` object, the paint method will call the Gunslinger draw method without any problem but the meaning of the `Gunslinger` `draw()` method is very different than what is intended.  In practice this problem tends to be unusual but it can happen.

Now in a language such as Java or C#, you have the concept of an explicit interface.  Just having a method with the same name isn't enough.  Your class needs to implement a common interface in order for a method to be 'the same message'.  For example, the equivalent of the above `paint` method in Java would be:

```java
void paint(Object... shapes) {
  for (Object shape : shapes) {
    shape.draw();
  }
}
```

But unlike the Python version this won't work.  It won't even compile.  The reason being that there's no `draw()` defined in the Object type.  To fix that we need a type such as `Shape` that defines the `draw()` method.  Now the method becomes:

```java
void paint(Shape... shapes) {
  for (Shape shape : shapes) {
    shape.draw();
  }
}
```

And works as expected.  There's still a big difference between this and the Python version: if I try to pass something in that doesn't implement `Shape`, I'm going to get a compile time error (or a runtime casting error.)  If I try to pass in my `Gunslinger` object, it will no longer work.  Likewise, if `Circle` and/or `Rectangle` don't implement the Shape interface, they won't be accepted either.  As far as the compiler is concerned, these two are no more similar to each other than they are to the `Gunslinger` version if there's no common interface between them.

So in short, with this kind of typing, the 'message' of a method is not the same just because the methods have the same name (and signature), the 'message' is defined by the method definition in the interface.  Without a common interface, `Circle.draw()` and `Rectangle.draw()` are just two methods that happen to have the same names but they are not considered the 'same message'

I think it's important to understand though that conceptually there's not a huge divide between the two approaches.  The difference is whether the interface (or contract) is implicit in the code or explicit.  `Gunslinger.draw()` doesn't become equivalent to `Shape.draw()` just because there is no compiled interface for `Shape`.

Comment: I see a risk with your explanation, as you used "Object" as the base class, which while correct, since it's entire function in the language is based on polymorphism, isn't the best example. I recommend "Shape", this is because when I was reading your answer, I had in my mind, that polymorphism includes the subclass will masquerade as the base class when passed to the function, then I noticed you just used "Object", instead of "Shape"..  I mention this because depending on how you intended, there could be room for argument there, and don't want to make the wrong assumption.

Comment: @DanChase I used Object to demonstrate that a `paint` method that doesn't know what it is getting is problematic.  The example could probably use some elaboration.  I was also trying to avoid dynamic/static typing since I think that can actually make this harder to understand while still satisfying the requirements of your typical curly-brace/semicolon language.  But it could be JS, I suppose. I'll revise the answer when I have more time.

Comment: no worries and no need, You've clarified, I was just worried that I over-reacted, and it sounds like I did.

Comment: @DanChase It's good feedback.  I'm going to revise and elaborate.

Comment: I tried to upvote but didn't realize I already did, so had to hit it again to correct. Great explanation that explores the differences and impacts of typing.

Answer (score 9):

> So `circle1` and `rectangle1` understood the same message `draw()` without using Polymorphism!

What makes you think they are not using Polymorphism?

> Am I missing something?

Yes: that what you describe *is* Polymorphism, by definition.

Comment: Indeed. Not explicitly defining the supertype, does not mean you're NOT using polymorphism; it only means you'll have a hard time enforcing it later on, when others tinker with your code and break the _implied_ contract.

Comment: This is clearly a correct answer in weakly typed languages, and also in strictly typed languages when `Circle ` and `Rectangle` share a common supertype. But do you think this is also valid when none of the former conditions is fulfilled? (I honestly don't know - do you?)

Comment: @DocBrown - I think Karl's answer nails it; essentially, the key aspect of type polymorphism (why we care about it) is that you can (in principle or dynamically) replace one implementation with a different one that semantically does "the same thing", without having to change the client. When that's not possible, the variable can't "change form"; i.e., even though the types support the same conceptual message, you can't use them polymorphically. So I'd say it's not valid in that case.

Comment: P.S. If you think of the message as it was conceptualized in the early days - a token of some sort that identifies the high-level operation - then you could say that, if you can't use the two polymorphically, the problem is that the calls aren't technically treated as the same message under the hood. E.g. say you have a vtable; in a call via `obj.vptr[func_offset]`, you could say that `func_offset` is the token that identifies the message - but only if there's a guarantee that it'll mean the same for the two types.

Comment: P.P.S. Oh, and JavaScript provides a different example of the same concept - a function is really a property on the object (e.g., you can do `text.toUpperCase()`, but also `text["toUpperCase"]()`), and the runtime uses the name of the function as the message token - which is what ultimately lets you use two largely unrelated objects in a polymorphic way.

Comment: @DocBrown runtime polymorphism is possible without inheritance in C++. See [Sean Parent's Runtime Polymorphism talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QGcVXgEVMJg).

Comment: Sure it is , one could use a technology like COM (Windows), but that was not what I actuslly meant.

Comment: @DocBrown: "This is clearly a correct answer in weakly typed languages, and also in strictly typed languages when `Circle` and `Rectangle` share a common supertype. But [is this] also valid when none of the former conditions is fulfilled?" – There is no generally accepted definition of "weakly typed" and "strictly typed", so it's impossible to answer without a precise definition of those terms. At least in Ruby, this is possible with `Circle` and `Rectangle` only sharing the trivial common super type `Object`, and according to a significant portion of definitions, Ruby is *not* weakly typed.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović: To be honest, I made a couple of (unstated) assumptions in my answer: I assume that there is a common protocol between the two (as explicitly stated in [Karl Bielefeldt's answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/409775/1352)), and I assume that the OP is talking about runtime dynamic ad-hoc polymorphism. Considering that the question cannot sensibly be answered without making such assumptions, I am now questioning myself whether answering was even the right move, or whether the question should be closed as unclear.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: what I wanted to know is indeed in Karl's answer, you gave me the right pointer, thanks.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović: The OP doesn't state whether they are talking about Parametric Polymorphism, Bounded Polymorphism, F-bounded Polymorphism, Subtype Polymorphism, Inclusion Polymorphism, Ad-Hoc Polymorphism, and whether they are talking about compile time / static or runtime / dynamic. All of those are important, and there are different answers here making different assumptions about those, coming to different conclusions based on those assumptions, and (like myself) without stating those assumptions.

Comment: Thank you, I was just going to write this. I have no idea what the other answers are spending so long trying to say. This is the very definition of polymorphism.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: "The OP doesn't state whether they are talking about [...]" - that's true. On the other hand, I think they are just starting to learn and don't understand polymorphism well enough to make those distinctions; they are trying to understand the quote. As everyone else, I made some assumptions regarding what the question is about, and to me, it made sense to focus on how the idea of the message plays into it, because it seemed that that's what the question revolves around.

Answer (score 3):

> But the above definition also apply if we don't use Polymorphism, [...]
>   So circle1 and rectangle1 understood the same message draw() without using Polymorphism!

This is a perfect example for a popular logical fallacy. 
Given the premise

```
  A implies B
```

one can **not** conclude that

```
   if we have B, therefore we also must have A.   <-- WRONG
```

The only valid conclusion would be:

```
If there's no B then there's certainly also no A.
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_tollens

Answer (score 2):

Here's a great example of polymorphism. Let's say we have the following classes to represent different types of bank accounts:

- current
- savings
- business
- shared

(And let's assume each inherits from an `account` super class.)

Then let's say we added the following methods to **each** of those classes:

- open()
- close()
- suspend()

That way we would know that to open a savings account on the system, we could use `savings.open()`. And the same for a business account: `business.open()`.

And if we wanted to close any account we would know we could use `.close()`, etc. Provided the different `.close()` methods did what we expected them to do, and closed each of the accounts, then **that would be polymorphism**.

If we didn't do that, and we used differently named methods (eg. `savings.delete()`, `shared.erase()`, `current.remove()`) it would get very confusing. Polymorphism is a practice which makes our code more intuitive and less confusing.

So your example of `circle.draw()` and `square.draw()` is a perfect example of Polymorphism. They are shapes, and so presumably inherit from a `shape` class. If you didn't use polymorphism, you would have methods like `circle.render()` and `square.create()`.

The fact that you've apparently created an instance of a circle class with the name "circle1" doesn't change anything.

In short: **Your example IS a demonstration of Polymorphism in its most basic form.**

Answer (score 1):

I think a key thing to remember about functions is what happens when you call them:

- They accept 0 or more arguments
- They have a return type
- They could have side effects

If your interface is as simple as just implementing a single method that accepts no arguments and has no meaningful return value, many things could probably implement the interface.

```
interface IDrawable {
    draw: () => any;
}
```

[image: Bugs Bunny drawing]

Bugs and Sam both implement you interface. A deck of cards implements your interface. Howerver, adding one return type makes it quite a different story.

```
interface IDrawable {
    draw: () => Image;
}
```

If your interface stated that the implementor had to return a picture, it's likely that Bugs would be the only one that could fit into your array of drawables.

Your example **is** polymorphism and depending on the application, might be useful. However more contextual interfaces can help with other cases where we need specific requirements.

Comment: "Bugs and Sam both implement you interface." - from a purely technical, language features–focused standpoint, that's true. But from a *design* standpoint, it's not, as it depends on the *meaning* of the operation, even though this constraint cannot be fully expressed in the language itself. If draw means "represent visually", then Sam's implementation breaks the Liskov Substitution Principle, and unlike Bugs', it will cause bugs, and/or chaos and mayhem :) But you make a good point - strive to express the meaning of the operation more closely using the language features available.

Answer (score 0):

One way to easily understand, is to think of a IS_A relationship.

A Ferarri IS A Car. So is a Ford Focus.

Polymorphism is saying, you write a function, that wants a car.. regardless of whether it's a ferarri or a ford focus. That being, the definition of your class.

```
result = relishOverItsExoticBeauty(car);
```

This will also work:

```
result = relishOverItsExoticBeauty(ferarri);
```

and so will this:

```
result = relishOverItsExoticBeauty(fordfocus);
```

Another feature of polymorphism that's important (and required for the above to work in any useful way) is the ability to override methods.

Don't confuse this with OOP, it's different. Just because you make an object with properties and methods, doesn't mean it's polymorphic. Some languages do some OOP and do not do polymorphism (at least very well).

Answer (score 0):

*Am I missing something?*

Yes, draw will ideally behave in it's own way in case of circle and rectangle. That is the definition, if you see closely.

Answer (score 0):

What you’re thinking of is called “duck-typing,” after the old saying, “If it looks like a duck, and walks like a duck, and quacks like a duck, it’s a duck.”

There are languages that use it extensively. The C++ standard library has largely shifted from defining class hierarchies, such as the ones in `<iostream>`, to assembling templates that use informal “concepts.” There is, for example, no formal class all containers or all iterators inherit from. If you can dereference it, increment it and compare it, it’s an iterator. In particular, native pointers are iterators. If `begin()` and `end()` return iterators (and the `end()` iterator holds no valid data, and is reachable by repeatedly incrementing the `begin()` iterator to obtain a sequence of valid iterators, etc.) it’s a container.

This has advantages over trying to implement multiple classes at once, not least performance.

There are things you cannot do this way, however. One is implementing abstract interfaces and dynamically passing in an object whose type you do not know at compile time. You cannot link to a library that accepts generic objects that support an interface: all the code must be a template in your header file. In many languages, the compiler must create different versions of the function for every possible version of the template, instead of generic code that would run on every possible object. (Or else it must compile to a higher-level intermediate code, not native code.) It’s also likely that someone will write some method called `draw()` that just coincidentally happens to compile with your code. If there is a formal class (or typeclass) interface, that cannot happen by accident: the code will only be able to use that interface if the programmer claims that a type supports it.

Answer (score 0):

### Background/Definitions

"Polymorphic" roughly translates to "multiply-shaped", and means that *a single piece of code* will work for *many different (data/code) structures*. Your code example isn't *quite* polymorphic, since you have one line of code for a `circle` and one for a `rectangle`; here's how we could make it truly polymorphic:

```
for shape in [circle1, rectangle1]:
  shape.draw()
```

Here the line of code `shape.draw()` is polymorphic, since that single line of code works for multiple data structures (a `circle` and a `rectangle`).

We can understand polymorphism in terms of "first-class functions/methods" (i.e. values which represent methods). Polymorphic code can work in multiple situations by first *fetching* a method which is appropriate for the current situation, then *running* that method.

In the above example, these two steps could be written like this:

```
for shape in [circle1, rectangle1]:
  myMethod = Object.lookup(shape, "draw")
  Method.invoke(myMethod)
```

I've made up the static methods `Object.lookup` and `Method.invoke`, but hopefully you get the idea: we're looking up the `"draw"` slot of the `shape` object, which will return a value `myMethod` representing that method. Since `Object.lookup` works the same way for any string and object it is not polymorphic. The static method `Method.invoke` will run `myMethod`; again, this works the same way for all method values, so it's also not polymorphic.

So why does OOP make such a big deal about polymorphism? There are two main reasons:

- Some languages support polymorphism (like `shape.draw()`) but *do not* support first-class methods (like `myMethod`). Java and C++ were examples of such languages, although newer versions so support first-class methods (called "lambdas"). In such languages we cannot write code involving things like `myMethod`, so the above explanation won't work in practice (although the *idea* still applies).
- The code `Object.lookup(shape, "draw")` is *dynamic*: the lookup is done at run-time, and we have no way to know if it will work (for example, instead of the literal string `"draw"`, we could instead take the string from a file or from user input). In the polymorphic code, the method name `draw` is *static*: it's always literally there in the code, which might gives us enough information to check whether the lookup will work *before* we run the code. Again, Java and C++ are examples of languages which will perform these checks (as part of their compilation).

(Languages like Java and C++ have had a large impact on programming, and OOP in particular, so it's not surprising that their features and style crop up a lot when describing OOP concepts like polymorphism. Other languages, like Python, don't do such checks, which leads to different styles like "duck typing" that others mention.)

One way to check whether a lookup will work is called *subtype polymorphism*, where the method name is associated with some explicit 'contract' (e.g. a "class", "interface", "signature", "abstract type", "existential type", "type class", etc. depending on the language) and we only allow lookups of that method for values which claim to fulfil that contract (e.g. "objects instantiating a class/subclass", "objects inheriting from a prototype", "modules implementing a signature", "types instantiating a type class", etc.).

### The Answer to Your Question

Checking for things like subtype polymorphism is *conservative*:

- Code which passes the check will work. For example, if we require a `Circle` object and the `Circle` class implements a `draw` method, then calling `draw` on the given object will succeed in finding an implementation to run.
- Code which would work might not pass the check. For example, if we try giving a `Rectangle` object to the code in the last example, the check will fail since it isn't a `Circle`. Yet, in this case, `Rectangle` has a `draw` method, so the code *would* work (if the failed check didn't stop us).

Your question is describing this second situation. We can think of type-checking as a form of mathematical proof: if we know that `shape` is a `Circle`, that implies is has a `draw` method, so we know it's safe to call `shape.draw()`. On the other hand, if we know that `shape` is *not* a `Circle`, we don't know whether it has a `draw` method of not, so it would be unsafe to allow calling `shape.draw()`.

Some languages (e.g. C++ and Java) will forbid these unsafe situations, so we need to make more complicated proofs to convince them that it's safe (e.g. having `Rectangle` and `Circle` inherit `draw` from some parent class, or implement the same `Drawable` interface, etc.). Other languages (e.g. Python and Smalltalk) will allow these unsafe situations, but then it's up to us to make sure our programs work as expected.

### Extra Info

Note that there are other forms of polymorphism too! For example "parametric polymorphism" describes code which doesn't care about some details of a value, and hence those details can have any type. For example, getting the length of a list:

```
def length(l):
  result = 0
  while l.next:
    result = result + 1
    l = l.next
  return result
```

This will work for lists of integers, lists of strings, lists of lists of booleans, etc. and is hence (parametrically) polymorphic.

In OOP the word "polymorphism" tends to mean subtype polymorphism, whilst parametric polymorphism tends to be called "generics". Languages which don't enforce checks, like Python, are more fuzzy when it comes to such classification: we can write Python code which uses (subtype) polymorpism (e.g. using classes), but we can also write Python code which *looks like* (subtype) polymorphism, without any explicit mechanism to enforce it (AKA "duck typing").

If our language supports first-class methods/functions, then we can write "higher-order functions" which act in a similar way to polymorphic code, further blurring the boundaries. For example:

```
def runOn(f, x):
  return f(x)

for (draw, shape) in [(drawCircle, circle1), (drawRectangle, rectangle1)]:
  runOn(draw, shape)
```